# How to add a page number (out of total) at end of beamer headline containing a miniframe

Tags: beamer, page-numbering, mini-frames, headline

I use beamer with a headline containing miniframes navigation content:

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}

\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=white, bg=black}

\begin{document}
    \section{First}
    \frame{First-first}
    \frame{First-second}
    \section{Second}
    \frame{Second-first}
    \frame{Second-second}
\end{document}
```

This give a headline filled with the miniframe:

[image: cutout of full headline]

I would like to add the page number (out of total, so x/y) at the end (right edge) of the headline. I would want some control over the spacing between the miniframes part (last section) and the pagenumbering part.

*Is it possible to add the page number there? If so, how?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we were anyway redefining the headline for your previous question, you could add the `page number in head/foot` template to your headline like this (change the width of the navigation however you like):

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}

\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=white, bg=black}
%\setbeamercolor{page number in head/foot}{fg=white}

\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[totalframenumber]

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}{section in head/foot}
    \vskip2pt
    \begin{minipage}[c]{.8\paperwidth}
      \insertnavigation{\linewidth}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}[c]{.2\paperwidth}
      \hfill\usebeamercolor[fg]{page number in head/foot}\usebeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}\quad\mbox{}
    \end{minipage}%
    \vskip4pt % <- change here
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \ifbeamer@theme@subsection%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{middle separation line head}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{subsection in head/foot}
      \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\insertsubsectionhead
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \fi%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \section{First}
    \frame{First-first}
    \frame{First-second}
    \section{Second}
    \frame{Second-first}
    \frame{Second-second}
\end{document}
```

[image]